# histograms chart widget in CMV application

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I am trying to build my first widget te creat charts or histograms, for use in the Configurable Map Viewer (CMV) im asking if you can help me with tutorial or something else can help me to build this  widget in the CMV application

Answer (score 1):

Look [Building custom widgets with CMV](http://docs.cmv.io/en/latest/contribute/BuildingCustomWidgets/).

Samples with charts from Esri's javascript API reference:

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/search/#/?q=chart&start=0&product=js-api-arcgis